# Verilog : how to build a 64 bit shifter from a 32 bit shifter (gate level)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, modelsim

I try to build a 32 bit shifter at gate level with my code like this and i work pretty well but it takes a lot of time to type.

```
module shiftbitleft(c,a,b);
output [31:0]c;
input [31:0]a;
input [4:0]b;
wire [31:0]d,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18
,d19,d20,d21,d22,d23,d24,d25,d26,d27,d28,d29,d30,d31;
assign d={31'd0,a[0]};
assign d1={30'd0,a[0],a[1]};
assign d2={29'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2]};
assign d3={28'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]};
assign d4={27'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]};
assign d5={26'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]};
assign d6={25'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]};
assign d7={24'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7]};
assign d8={23'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8]};
assign d9={22'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9]};
assign d10={21'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10]};
assign d11={20'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11]};
assign d12={19'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12]};
assign d13={18'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13]};
assign d14={17'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14]};
assign d15={16'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15]};
assign d16={15'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16]};
assign d17={14'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17]};
assign d18={13'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18]};
assign d19={12'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19]};
assign d20={11'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20]};
assign d21={10'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21]};
assign d22={9'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22]};
assign d23={8'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23]};
assign d24={7'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24]};
assign d25={6'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25]};
assign d26={5'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25],a[26]};
assign d27={4'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25],a[26],a[27]};
assign d28={3'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25],a[26],a[27],a[28]};
assign d29={2'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25],a[26],a[27],a[28],a[29]};
assign d30={1'd0,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25],a[26],a[27],a[28],a[29],a[30]};
assign d31={a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19],a[20],a[21],a[22],a[23],a[24],a[25],a[26],a[27],a[28],a[29],a[30],a[31]};
mux32 m1(d,b,c[0]);
mux32 m2(d1,b,c[1]);
mux32 m3(d2,b,c[2]);
mux32 m4(d3,b,c[3]);
mux32 m5(d4,b,c[4]);
mux32 m6(d5,b,c[5]);
mux32 m7(d6,b,c[6]);
mux32 m8(d7,b,c[7]);
mux32 m9(d8,b,c[8]);
mux32 m10(d9,b,c[9]);
mux32 m11(d10,b,c[10]);
mux32 m12(d11,b,c[11]);
mux32 m13(d12,b,c[12]);
mux32 m14(d13,b,c[13]);
mux32 m15(d14,b,c[14]);
mux32 m16(d15,b,c[15]);
mux32 m17(d16,b,c[16]);
mux32 m18(d17,b,c[17]);
mux32 m19(d18,b,c[18]);
mux32 m20(d19,b,c[19]);
mux32 m21(d20,b,c[20]);
mux32 m22(d21,b,c[21]);
mux32 m23(d22,b,c[22]);
mux32 m24(d23,b,c[23]);
mux32 m25(d24,b,c[24]);
mux32 m26(d25,b,c[25]);
mux32 m27(d26,b,c[26]);
mux32 m28(d27,b,c[27]);
mux32 m29(d28,b,c[28]);
mux32 m30(d29,b,c[29]);
mux32 m31(d30,b,c[30]);
mux32 m32(d31,b,c[31]);
endmodule
```

I wonder if there is any way that i can build a 64 bit shifter from a 32bit shifter so that i dont have to build a 64 bit from scratch like the above code. Thank you very much.

Comment: you 'd better use a verilog shift operator instead of all this typing. I do not think that there is much you can do otherwise. You can try to generate this code with a scripting language, like python.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using all of the above why not use a shift operator:

```
module shiftbitleft(c,a,b);
output [31:0]c;
input [31:0]a;
input [4:0]b;

assign c = a << b;

endmodule
```

You can expand this to 64 bits easily by changing the sizes of the input and outputs.

Incidentally if you do find yourself writing endless lines of Verilog to some task and there isn't a language construct or other technique to solve the issue directly you should probably make use of generate statements. They make this a lot simple without extra typing and are a lot easier for others to review.

See: https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-generate-block